# Dojo build for dijit creates file containing only undefined;

Tags: dojo, dojo-build

I'm creating a custom build for my dojo application. I've created the following profile.js:

```javascript
var profile = {
    basePath: "../../../",
    releaseDir: "./releases/custom",
    packages: ['dojo', 'dijit', 'dojox' ],
    cssOptimize: 'comments',
    mini: true,
    optimize: 'comments',
    layerOptimize: 'comments',
    stripControle: 'all',
    selectorEngine: 'lite',
    layers : {
        'dojo/dojo': {         
            include: ['dojo/dojo', 'dojo/domReady', 'dojo/_base/declare', "dojo/on", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/query", "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/parser", "dojo/_base/connect", "dojo/DeferredList", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/store/Observable"],         
            boot: true,         
            customBase: true   
        }, 
        'dijit/dijit' : {
            include: ["dijit/registry","dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/Textarea", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dijit/form/CheckBox", "dijit/form/Button"],
            boot: true,
            customBase: true
        },
    },
}
```

The `dojo/dojo.js` is created, but the `dijit/dijit.js` contains only template text:

> //>>built
>
> undefined;

However, the file `dijit.js.uncompressed.js` is created correctly (998 KB).

Why the dojo build behaves that way? What error is in that configuration? Dojo documentation is quite enigmatic.

**--edit--**

It seems to be problem with specifying output files. After changing 'dijit/dijit'`enter code here` to `'dojo/dijit'` file `dijit.js` is created in `dojo` subdirectory. If I want to create a build with custom name, I need to create it in `dojo` subdirectory too. Otherwise the empty file (containing only `undefined;)` is created.

Comment: While running the build process are there any warnings or errors in the log?

Comment: @BuffaloBuffalo yes, about some unresolved plugins, but nothing relevant for that file. However, if I change 'dijit/dijit' to 'dojo/dijit', the file dijit.js with built layer is created.

Comment: That is interesting... What is your folder structure (e.g `dojo-release` folder with `dojo-release/dojo/`, `dojo-release/dijit/`, `dojo-release/dojox/`)?

Comment: Release directory contains folders dijit, dojo and dojox. Dojo is in version 1.9